# Could not initialize class caused by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError GWT

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, gwt-rpc, gwt2

I get the following error while calling my GWT RPC function,

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 500
```

I did add the remoteservicepath and also servlet name and mapping  in my web.xml, but i get the error

> Could not initialize class com.logins.server.Putquestion Caused by:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor19.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)...

Note: 
1)com.logins.server.PutQuestion is server code that implements the rpc Interface  defined at client side.

Any guesses where i am going wrong ?

Comment: UPDATE :Things worked fine when i again restarted eclipse IDE,Strange why it happened!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the servlet class is present in war/WEB-INF/classes folder.

Answer (score 1):

You have classes in your classpath of your editor but not during runtime.

The trace says that you have some exception thrown within the constructor that gets propagated to the classloader. Try wrapping your constructor with try/catch and print the stack trace. Probably you are looking up the database/file which could be down/not present.

Comment: I just restarted the eclipse IDE and things went fine,I am still strange why it showed error and it went fine when i restarted eclipse ,between thank you much for suggesstion